# CASE within SELECT and JOIN to assign a new value to column

Tags: sql-server-2008

In the example below, i need to know how to set the value of `MGR.manager_name` to `''` (empty string) when the value of `MGR.report_to = 'A'`. Basically, when the `MGR.report_to ='A'`, the employee will not have a manager and manager_name will be empty. I cannot get the code below to work. Is there another way to re-write this to get it to work. Thanks! JK

```
SELECT
    EMP.employee_id AS emplid,
    EMP.employee_first_name AS firstname,
    EMP.employee_last_name AS lastname,
    EMP.employee_address AS address,
CASE MGR.manager_name
    WHEN MGR.report_to ='A' THEN ''
    THEN  'B'
    ELSE 'C' 
END AS managername,
    MGR.manager_id AS managerid,
    MGR.report_to
FROM Employee_Table EMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Manager_Table MGR ON EMP.employee_id  = MGR.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Update here

```
 SELECT
    EMP.employee_id AS emplid,
    EMP.employee_first_name AS firstname,
    EMP.employee_last_name AS lastname,
    EMP.employee_address AS address,
CASE when MGR.report_to ='A' then '' 

END AS managername,
    MGR.manager_id AS managerid,
    MGR.report_to
FROM Employee_Table EMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Manager_Table MGR ON EMP.employee_id  = MGR.employee_id
```

if you need more case just repeat the case when line

When you use a case you have to repeat case when boolean then value and finish with end as 'column name'